# Comparing ordinal age group data from two samples with different scales

Tags: two-sample

I have two samples of data from one population: 
Sample 1= 4,491 participants
Sample 2 = 262 participants

I want to compare age of participants in each sample but both samples have a different scale on which participants logged their ages.

Sample 1 scale = under 21, 22-24 years, 25-34 years, 35-44 years, 45-54 years, 55-64 years, 65 or over.

Sample scale 2 = 17 years or under, 18-24, 25-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51-60, 61 or over.

What can I do?

Comment: I keep thinking about this and can't come up with a solution that wouldn't potentially introduce artefacts that could lead to spurious results at the inference stage. I assume you want to know whether one sample is older than the other. Could you not just compare the proportions of people appearing in the different groups? For example, if most of the people in sample 1 are in the young ranges and most of the people in sample 2 are in the older range, then sample 2 is probably older on average.

Comment: The data spread is similar for both samples. As they both come from one population, and my sample is the smaller of the two samples, I thought it might be useful to use a larger sample to help validate my smaller sample. I am a novice here so please tell me if this is not possible/a stupid idea!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to do something here using methods developed for incomplete contingency tables. Suppose for example you just have three categories for each sample. For A under 18, 19 to 24, 25 and over and for B under 16, 17 to 30, 31 and over. You can now view this as coming from a table with five categories: under 15, 17 to 18, 19 to 24, 25 to 30, 31 and over but where for quite a few categories in each sample you only know the number in two adjacent cells fused together. So in sample A the number under 18 corresponds to cells under 16 and 17 to 18 fused but in sample B you know under 16 for sure.

For some references look at the manual for this R [package](http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=gllm) where there are some examples if you use R but also reference to some papers outlining the method.

This is not going to give you a simple answer but it may help to find a method which suits your scientific question.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I will do some research on your suggestion.